# Syncing dyRangeSelector from dygraph with setWindow of timevis

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have synced the setWindow from timevis with the dyrangeselector from the dygraph, in order to zoom in and out depending on the rangeselector of the dygraph.

However, I am trying to maintain data in the timevis after sliding in and out from the dygraph.

[image]

Because after adding some item on the timevis, and sliding the dyrangeselector, all the items disappear but I do not understand why.

[image]

Does someone had this similar issue?

```
**********************************

        rv <- reactiveValues()
    rv$df <- data.frame() %>%
      mutate(id = "",
             start = "",
             content = "")

    ################## client-side p_ARIMA ######################
    
    output$p_ARIMA_Custom <- renderTimevis({
        
        config <- list(
            editable = TRUE,
            align = "center",
            orientation = "top",
            minorLabels = FALSE,
            majorLabels = FALSE,
            timeAxis = list(scale = "month", step = 1),
            onAdd = htmlwidgets::JS('function(item, callback) {
      item.content = "Hello!<br/>" + item.content;
      callback(item);
    }'),
            onUpdate = htmlwidgets::JS("function(item, callback) {
       item.content = prompt('Edit items text:', item.content);
    if (item.content != null) {
      callback(item); // send back adjusted item
    }
    else {
      callback(null); // cancel updating the item
    }
  }"))

       timevis(data = rv$df,
                options = config) %>%
            setWindow(start = input$p_ARIMA_date_window[[1]], end = input$p_ARIMA_date_window[[2]],
                      options = list(animation = FALSE))       
    })
    
    # based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165876/8099834
    output$p_ARIMA_Custom_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(input$p_ARIMA_Custom_data,
                rownames = FALSE,
                editable = TRUE,
                options = list(pageLength = 10))

    }, server = FALSE)

**********************************

                      tabPanel(
                        "ARIMA",
                        icon = icon("area-chart"),
                        h4("Auto Regressive Integrated Moving Average (ARIMA) Model"),
                        br(),
                        dygraphOutput("p_ARIMA"),
                        value = 1,
                        br(),
                        timevisOutput("p_ARIMA_Custom"),
                        br(),
                        dataTableOutput("p_ARIMA_Custom_table")
                      ),

**************************
```

I am struggling in having a reprex.

Comment: I see no evident error. Did you try to debug using `cat(input$p_ARIMA_date_window[[1]],'\n')` before the `timevis`call to see in console what value is used?